# assign hex value for short data type

Tags: java

I know that assigning 0x9d for short data type will work. but when i'm print it out, it displays 157. it should retain as 0x9d because im planning to pass that data to a library which accepts short data type only and should be 0x9d for example.

here's the portion of my code where i got the error.

```
short module_id = (short) 0x9d; // defined in system.txt
System.out.print("hello: " + String.format("%x", module_id));
roamerLocator.receiveMsg(module_id);
}

protected void receiveMsg(short moduleId) {

try {
System.out.println("\ninside: " + moduleId);
GctMsg gctMsg = GctLib.receive(moduleId);
```

this is for my ss7 configuration . the defined parameters in ss7 configuration should be accepting 0x9d instead of decimal which is 157. and the "GctMsg gctMsg = GctLib.receive(moduleId);" accepts only short data type

Comment: This isn't clear; you're using `String.format` to render the value as hex, so what's the problem?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth . look at my try&catch. the moduleId prints 157. instead of 0x9d. it should retain as 0x9d.

Comment: Well use `String.format` there as well, then!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the last line on my post accepts only short data type which is the `GctMsg gctMsg = GctLib.receive(moduleId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what hexadecimal and decimal are meant to represent.

Decimal is a numerical representation in base 10 - you know, counting from 0 to 9.  That's the system we're used to.

Hexadecimal is a numerical representation in base 16 - which goes from 0 to F.

In effect, your concern is that 157 isn't the same as `0x9D`, [when it actually is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0x9D).

Hexadecimal is more a formal representation, and it doesn't change the underlying value of the number.  So, you should be okay to see 157 passed in to your method.

If you really want to see it again as `0x9d`, you can use `String#format` inside of your `System.out.println`:

```
System.out.println("\ninside: " + String.format("%x", moduleId));
```

Comment: now i get it. so meaning. it doesn't matter if it's 157 or 0x9d . because their value will be just the same.